# How can i calculate grand total from datagridview with one date?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want code to calculate grand total with different added date. Like daily sales report preparation. I have to calculate total of Grand total with same added date in this pic
[image: Data]

This is the code I have so far

```
private void btnsubtootal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dgvPurchase.Rows.Count; ++i) {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvPurchase.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    }

    txtNetSales.Text = "" + sum.ToString();        
}

private void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
        conn.Open();
        str = "select * from tbl_sales";


        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "grand_total");

        dgvPurchase.DataMember = "grand_total";

        dgvPurchase.DataSource = ds;

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How do you bound the data to your gridview? Do you need to select the "row" to calculate your total?

Comment: Code is shown above alicia

Comment: That’s how you’re trying to calculate, but what I’m asking is how do you bound your data to your gridview

Comment: i have added code in my question will you please help me? i need total of Grand total column added in same date.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to calculate your "Net Sales" value with a button, then you could do something like this:

```
enum GVColumns
{
    //We make an enum for our GridView columns
    Id = 0,
    CustomerName,
    BillNum,
    SubTotal,
    Discount,
    GrandTotal,
    Credit,
    AddedDate,
    AddedBy
}

private void btnsubtootal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal grandtotalByDate = 0;
    DateTime searchedDate = new DateTime();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPurchase.SelectedRows)
    {
        var txtDateAddedValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.AddedDate].Value.ToString();
        searchedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDateAddedValue); //get our "added_date" to search
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPurchase.Rows)
    {
        var txtGrandTotalValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.GrandTotal].Value.ToString(); //"grand_total" cell value as string
        var txtDateAddedValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.AddedDate].Value.ToString(); //"added_date" cell value as string
        var rowDateAddedValue = DateTime.Parse(txtDateAddedValue);

        //check if our dates match
        if (rowDateAddedValue.Date == searchedDate.Date)
        {
            //add "grand_total" values if dates match
            grandtotalByDate += decimal.Parse(txtGrandTotalValue);
        }
    }

    txtNetSales.Text = grandtotalByDate.ToString("N2");
}
```

But i would really recommend changing the logic of using a button, to just using the event `RowStateChanged` of your `GridView` so you just select your Row and it calculates it:

```
private void dgvPurchase_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        var txtDateAddedValue = e.Row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.AddedDate].Value.ToString();

        DateTime searchedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDateAddedValue);
        decimal grandtotalByDate = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPurchase.Rows)
        {
            var txtDAV = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.AddedDate].Value.ToString();
            var dateRow = DateTime.Parse(txtDAV);

            if (dateRow.Date == searchedDate.Date)
            {
                var txtGrandTotalValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.GrandTotal].Value.ToString();
                grandtotalByDate += decimal.Parse(txtGrandTotalValue);
            }
        }

        lblTotalByDate.Text = grandtotalByDate.ToString("N2");
    }
}
```

Comment: +  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException            for this line           var txtGrandTotalValue = row.Cells[(int)GVColumns.grand_total].Value.ToString();

Comment: Probably because your GridView has more or less columns than what i defined in my enum `GVColumns`. You should change that with the amount of columns that gives your query (`"select * from tbl_sales"`).

Comment: columns that  you entered is same as i entered but the error is still same.